# Run Python with different configuration

Tags: python, devops

I am trying to hav an application that runs on local and the cloud. In the clould (GCP) its uses different URI for databases and other services.

I have made a configuration file in the next way.

config.ini file

```
[PROD]
DATABASE = mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@mongodbscrapperconf-lzq.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority


[DEV]
DATABASE = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27027/
```

And a class that give me those values, and is coded in the different way.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os

class Config:
   """Interact with configuration variables."""

   configParser = ConfigParser()
   configFilePath = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'))

   @classmethod
   def initialize(cls, newhire_table):
       """Start config by reading config.ini."""
       cls.configParser.read(cls.configFilePath)

   @classmethod
   def prod(cls, key):
       """Get prod values from config.ini."""
       return cls.configParser.get('PROD', key)

   @classmethod
   def dev(cls, key):
       """Get dev values from config.ini."""
       return cls.configParser.get('DEV', key)
```

I am lost now, for example how do I use this `Config.dev("DATABASE")` how do I make it to run the Config.dev when I run in local, and run `Config.prod("DATABASE")` when I am in the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have different files for development and production (each on its respective server), and have a single function to access them? That way, the function will retrieve different data (corresponding to the config file on the server) depending on where you access it.

For example, on `config.ini` on the production server you would have:

```
[DB]
DB_URI = mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@mongodbscrapperconf-lzq.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

And on `config.ini` on your local machine:

```
[DB]
DB_URI = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27027/
```

Then your class could look like this, for instance:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os

class Config:
   """Interact with configuration variables."""

   configParser = ConfigParser()
   configFilePath = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'))

   @classmethod
   def initialize(cls, newhire_table):
       """Start config by reading config.ini."""
       cls.configParser.read(cls.configFilePath)

   @classmethod
   def get(cls, key1, key2):
       """Get values from config.ini."""
       return cls.configParser.get(key1, key2)
```

And you would just access your data with `Config.get("DB", "DB_URI")`.

Comment: Off topic, and if the code is under a version control system like Git, how do you encapsulate the database connection and credentials to remain hidden?

Comment: @cpinamtz Security credentials should NEVER be stored or visible in Git, so first of all the `config.ini`file should be added to `.gitignore`. Then you need a solution to fetch the latest configs in your server. You could either update it manually, use environment variables in some way (if your cloud provider makes it easier to update them remotely) or set up a startup script in which the server downloads the file from a safe repository (like an IP-restricted S3 bucket, for example)